# Create a single object from multiple foreach loops

Tags: jquery, foreach

I am trying to create an object for a single player that has all of that players ranks over all of the seasons available.

I've been getting the information and am iterating through it.  The each loops work, but I think I'm overwriting parts of the object as I iterate through.  I'm not sure how to get all of the information without overwriting part of the object.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var playerObj;
var username = page.find('.profile_player-name').text();
if(username) {
    var seasons = page.find('.profile_seasons .tab-pane');
    var seasonsObj;
    $.each(seasons, function(i) {
        var statsObj;
        var season = $(seasons[i]);
        var season_number = season.attr('id');
        var season_playlists = season.find('.row > .col-md-3');
        $.each(season_playlists, function(i) {
            var playlist = $(season_playlists[i]);
            var playlist_title = playlist.find('.panel-title').text();
            var playlist_rating = playlist.find('.profile_tier-name').text().match(/\d+/g);
            if(playlist_rating) {
                playlist_rating = playlist_rating[0];   
            }
            var playlist_rank = playlist.find('.profile_tier-name strong').text();
            var playlist_rank_icon = "http://rocketleaguestats.com/" + playlist.find('img').attr('src');
            statsObj = {
                title:playlist_title, 
                rating:playlist_rating, 
                rank: {rank_name:playlist_rank, rank_icon:playlist_rank_icon}
            };
            console.log(statsObj);
        });
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This should return something like this:

```
object = {
    username: "name",
    seasons:
        season_1: 
            rank: 
                rank_name: "Gold",
                rank_icon: http://....jpg,
            rating: "800",
            title: "Ranked Standard"
        season_2: 
            rank: 
                rank_name: "Gold",
                rank_icon: http://....jpg,
            rating: "800",
            title: "Ranked Standard"
        season_3: 
            rank: 
                rank_name: "Gold",
                rank_icon: http://....jpg,
            rating: "800",
            title: "Ranked Standard"
}
```

But I'm not sure how to add each different season as it's own piece of the object, with the different variable name (season_1 vs season_3).

How do I add each `season_#` as it's own part of the object dynamically?  There may be 1 to many seasons.

Comment: How do I add each season_# as it's own part of the object dynamically? There may be 1 to many seasons. Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve.?

Comment: @void, The object I've posted (second code block) is what I want to achieve.  I think my main question at this point is how do I make an object and use a variable as the key name?  When I go through the loops right now and try to make this object, I keep overwriting the seasons, so I only get 1 season instead of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add properties to an object, but the property name is variable, you can use the `[]` syntax. In your case, you can achieve what you want with a few simple changes.

First, just initialize your object

```
var seasonsObj = {
    username: username,
    seasons: {}
};
```

Then, in your loop, you can add properties to `seasonsObj.seasons` like this:

```
seasonObj.seasons['season_' + i] = statsObj;
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but `'season_' + i` may need to be changed to `'season_' + season_number` depending on OP's requirements.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable say `data`, now add a key value pair to it like:

```
var data = {};
var playerObj;
var username = page.find('.profile_player-name').text();
if(username) {
    var seasons = page.find('.profile_seasons .tab-pane');
    var seasonsObj;
    $.each(seasons, function(i) {
        var statsObj;
        var season = $(seasons[i]);
        var season_number = season.attr('id');
        var season_playlists = season.find('.row > .col-md-3');
        $.each(season_playlists, function(i) {
            var playlist = $(season_playlists[i]);
            var playlist_title = playlist.find('.panel-title').text();
            var playlist_rating = playlist.find('.profile_tier-name').text().match(/\d+/g);
            if(playlist_rating) {
                playlist_rating = playlist_rating[0];   
            }
            var playlist_rank = playlist.find('.profile_tier-name strong').text();
            var playlist_rank_icon = "http://rocketleaguestats.com/" + playlist.find('img').attr('src');
            statsObj = {
                title:playlist_title, 
                rating:playlist_rating, 
                rank: {rank_name:playlist_rank, rank_icon:playlist_rank_icon}
            };
            data["season_"+(i+1)] = statsObj; // Add a key value pair here.
            console.log(statsObj);
        });
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
```